# vue.js .net7 CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, .net-7.0

I'm trying to learn vue.js with .net7 and stuck in weird stuff.
i settup my Program.cs to this:

```
app.UseCors(opts =>
{
    opts.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
});
```

My web api responds to swagger so no problem there.
The problem came on vue.js:

```
let result = axios.get(reqUrl).then(response => Response(response)).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.toJSON());
});
```

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

The funny stuff of this is that the api is actually hit - does it make sense at all?

Comment: You're not listing any Web origins as allowed in your CORS configuration. Allow the Web origin of your frontend.

Comment: You wrote: _The funny stuff of this is that the api is actually hit - does it make sense at all?_ Yes, it does, because your request is so-called [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests); no CORS preflight takes place for such requests.

Comment: you suggest this adding web origins on cors configuration - 
correct me if i'm wrong - your suggestion isn't this 
""app.UseCors(opts =>
{
    opts.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
});

Comment: `app.UseCors(opts => { opts.WithOrigins("https://your-frontend-origin").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials(); })`

Comment: hello. i follow your advice and it works - so thanks.
but - is this standard behaviour ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and also the implementation of .NET's CORS middleware.